# how to configure Seedstack application to work in offline mode?

Tags: offline, seedstack

We would like to make available few screens in offline mode when no network is available.

We want to use HTML5 caching feature and we are able to cache few HTMLs and JS files, but can we cache the main configuration file ?

Is this the right approach? Can you please suggest correct approach w.r.t Seed framework.

Answer (score 0):

Before going further, please note that HTML5 Application Cache seems to be a feature [currently deprecated](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#offline). That said, **you can use the HTML5 Application Cache with SeedStack** altough the number of files involved in loading the application makes it a bit impractical, as this process is not currently automated.

To achieve offline mode with a SeedStack Web application you must:

- **Customize the masterpage template.** The default template doesn't contain the manifest attribute so you must replace it with your own. You can lookup the `masterpage.html` or `masterpage-fallback.html` files from the classpath to use as a starting point. Add the following configuration property to point to your own masterpage template:

  ```
  org.seedstack.w20.masterpage-template = path/to/my-masterpage.html
  ```
- **Add the `manifest` attribute** on the `<html>` tag of your masterpage template, pointing to the HTML5 appcache manifest:

  ```
  <html manifest="my-app.appcache" ...>
  ```
- **Add an exhaustive manifest to your application web resources**, like under `src/main/webapp` or under `META-INF/resources`.

My testing shows that for a just-generated Web application (using the business theme), you need to add [63 URLs to your manifest](https://gist.github.com/adrienlauer/1f1d2a3a349afa9f175f96b1a2592322) to make it work.

To ease your manifest maintenance, you can choose to disable the cache-busting mechanism by removing the `data-w20-app-version` attribute on the `<html>` tag. This will remove the version suffix in all URLs.

In IE/Edge you have to be careful for some restrictions or limits:

- There is a number limit of cache entries (1000 in IE10, don't know in newer versions).
- The is a size limit of the whole cache based upon the size of the client machine volume.
- The manifest must be served with the text/cache-manifest mime type.
- No resource must be served with the no-store cache option.

More info on Edge here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/dev-guide/networking-and-connectivity/application-cache/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. We are trying to make this work however we are facing issue with authentication in offline mode. How do you think we need to manage authentication in offline?

Comment: We are able to setup the SEED application properly and its working perfectly in CHROME browser. However on IE 11 and EDGE the same application is not caching the files. We are getting **AppCache Fatal Error** on console and its not caching anything. Also please note that without SEED, for a simple web application we are able to make it work even on IE.